# need to tick the checkbox in Datagridview C#

Tags: c#

I need to tick the checkbox in datagridview.in my case, I wanna do validation when the user going to untick the checkbox, [image]

I wanna tick the checkbox after message will show

```
private void dgvBookingType_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dgvRow = dgvBookingType.CurrentRow;
        if (dgvRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "True")
        {
            dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = true;
            if (_dsEvent.Tables.Contains("PackageBookingType"))
            {
                if (_dsEvent.Tables["PackageBookingType"] != null)
                {
                    DataRow[] selectedRow = _dsEvent.Tables["PackageBookingType"].Select("BookingTypeId=" + dgvRow.Cells[1].Value + " ");

                    if (selectedRow.Length > 0)
                        oUtilOptimised.ShowGenericUIValidation("There are packages that belong to the selected booking type added to the event. Remove the packages in order to disable the selected booking type", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, this, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

please help me

Comment: How are you adding data to the datagrid?

Comment: HI mark  dgvBookingType.DataSource = _dsEvent.Tables["BookingTypes"];

Comment: Is it WinForms? Add tag.

Comment: Try setting the checkBox column readonly and write code in dgv.CellClick event to tick/untick the checkbox.